# Parse and Aggregate Google Analytics Browser Version CSV Data

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

Google Analytics treats incremental browser versions as different, so my reports are useless for drawing any helpful conclusions. eg Chrome 45.0.2454.93 is considered a different browser than 45.0.2454.85.

I want to write a Python 2 app that grabs a Google Analytics CSV and aggregates session info for major browser versions.

I'm new to Python but here's my attempt...

```
from __future__ import division
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

RAWFile = 'somefile.csv'

def default_val():
    return [0, 0]

def aggregateaway():
    with open(RAWFile, 'r') as inf:
        has_header = csv.Sniffer().has_header(inf.read(1024))
        inf.seek(0)  # rewind
        incsv = csv.reader(inf)
        if has_header:
            next(incsv)  # skip header row

    reader = csv.DictReader(incsv, 'r')

    BrowserVersion = defaultdict(default_val)
    for row in reader:
        Sessions = int(row["Sessions"])
        BrowserVersion[row["BrowserVersion"]][0] += Sessions

    writer = csv.writer(open('out.csv', 'w'))
    writer.writerow(["BrowserVersion", "Sessions"])
    writer.writerows([BrowserVersion] + BrowserVersion[BrowserVersion] for BrowserVersion in BrowserVersion)
```

I have two problems that I know about:

1. I get `ValueError('I/O operation on closed file',)` - I think it's because of the logic I use to skip the leading rows before the data.
2. I'm not sure how to programatically group major browser versions. Is it `left(BrowserVersion, 2)`? Even so this is flawed because of other browsers versioning conventions. Perhaps I could search for the first `.` and then apply the left, x number of characters. How would I add that to the code above?

Edit: Some sample CSV data:

```
# ----------------------------------------
# My Site
# Web Browsers
# 20150828-20150927
# ----------------------------------------

Browser,Operating System,Browser Version,Sessions,Bounce Rate
Safari,iOS,8.0,"1,681",68.91%
Chrome,Windows,45.0.2454.85,"1,200",40.98%
Chrome,Windows,45.0.2454.93,"2,273",40.98%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I ended up using with a lot of help from a colleague. Hopefully Google decide to add this feature to Analytics some time soon:)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import csv
import operator
import pprint

inputfilename = 'input.csv'
outputfilename = 'output.csv'

values = []
with open(inputfilename, 'rb') as csvfile: #Open file
    reader = csv.DictReader(filter(lambda row: row[0]!='#', csvfile)) #Skip rows with #
    header = reader.next().values()[0] #Gives a list of field names
    for rows in reader:
        row = rows.values()[0]
        values.append({header[i]: row[i] for i in range(len(header))}) #Creates list of csv data in a dictionary

report = {} #Define empty dictionary to aggregate data into

for value in values:
    browserstring = value["Operating System"] + " - " + value["Browser"] + " - " + value["Browser Version"].split('.')[0] #Split browser version by '.' to get major version release
    if value["Browser"] <> '': #Skip to next to avoid GA column totals in output (i.e. those with a blank browser value)
        if browserstring in report:
            report [browserstring] += int(value["Sessions"].replace(',','')) #Remove number comma formatting, sum data
        else:
            report [browserstring] = int(value["Sessions"].replace(',','')) #Remove number formatting and add new reecord (if it does not exist already already)
    else:
        next

sorted_report = sorted(report.items(), reverse=True, key=operator.itemgetter(1)) #Convert dictionary to tuple to sort values in descending order

#pprint.pprint(sorted_report) #for debugging

with open(outputfilename,'w') as out: #Let's print this to file
    csv_out=csv.writer(out)
    csv_out.writerow(['Aggregated Browser Version - Major']) #Title
    csv_out.writerow(['Browser','Sessions']) #Column headers
    for row in sorted_report: #Data from ordered tuple list
        csv_out.writerow(row)
```

Output CSV example two rows:

[image]